# Add pixel offset to angular material cdk 'scrollToIndex'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Is it possible to add a pixel offset with `scrollToIndex` from:

https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api

For example here's my working code:

```
      this.scrollViewport.scrollToIndex(
        this.index + 1,
        'smooth'
      );
```

This works, but I'd like to sometimes add 20 pixels to the end of the scroll. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrollToOffset` instead [see here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api#scrollToOffset).

```js
 this.scrollViewport.scrollToOffset(
   offset,
   behavior
);
```

Or you use `setRenderedContentOffset` after you initial scroll.

```js
 this.scrollViewport.setRenderedContentOffset(
   offset,
   'to-start' | 'to-end'
);
```